# Is a gas fireplace enough to heat a small cottage?

Tags: fireplace

I have a ranch style 544 sq foot cottage 16x32 it is long and very narrow. I would like to install a gas fireplace for a heat source but as well as the ambiance. Do you think with proper blown in insulation, new windows that a gas insert would work. I like a nice 72 degree house. I have several new ceiling fans with high catherdral ceilings so it is like a two story without the usable second story. Any suggestions would be helpful. I understand I need to have a rather large unit (btu) due to the high ceilings, just want to be sure that this will be efficient. I plan to purchase a good blower and wall thermostat as well.

Comment: If you're going to use it that intensively, make sure exhaust is vented to outside (after passing thru heat exchanger/blower). For casual decorative use, it's not uncommon to ignore CO/CO2; for heating purposes, you really can't.

Answer (score 1):

I'd talk to the Fireplace dealer/installer to confirm, but yes, that should work provided:

- you use a blower (sounds like you have)
- your house isn't chopped up into too many rooms
- given the high ceilings, I'd strongly suggest installing a ceiling fan as well to help. If you don't, you may end up with one really hot room, and a bunch of only 'warm' rooms.